# str object not callable when converting int variable to using str function

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I'm sorry if this was asked already I have been sifting through past questions and cannot seem to find an answer. I am fairly new at python too.

What I am trying to do is write the word and r and c variable to an output file but formatted with a space between the word and variable (the format being the longest word of list - word I am looking at).

I have tried this, yet it comes up with a "str object not callable"

```
row_variable = str(r)
```

Here is the traceback when i tried it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\CS303E\WordSearch.py", line 106, in <module>
  main ()
File "C:\CS303E\WordSearch.py", line 84, in main
  output.write(list_of_words[i]+spaces+str(row_variable)+str(column_variable))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Here is my code:

```
# Find longest word in list of words
max_length = 0
for i in list_of_words:
  if len(i) > max_length:
    max_length = len(i)
# Open output file found.txt
output = open('found.txt','w')

# Check for list of words
for i in range(len(list_of_words)):
  flag = False
  for j in range(len(rows)):
    if list_of_words[i] in rows[j]:
      r = j + 1
      c = rows[j].find(list_of_words[i]) + 1
      num_spaces = max_length - len(list_of_words[i])
      spaces = ' ' * num_spaces
      output.write(list_of_words[i])
      flag = True
  for j in range(len(rev_rows)):
    if list_of_words[i] in rev_rows[j]:
      r = j + 1
      c = num_col - rev_rows[j].find(list_of_words[i])
      print(list_of_words[i], r, c)
      flag = True
  for j in range(len(columns)):
    if list_of_words[i] in columns[j]:
      r = j + 1
      c = columns[j].find(list_of_words[i]) + 1
      print(list_of_words[i], c, r) 
      flag = True
  for j in range(len(rev_columns)):
    if list_of_words[i] in rev_columns[j]:
      r = j + 1
      c = num_col - rev_rows[j].find(list_of_words[i])
      print(list_of_words[i], c, r)
      flag = True
  if flag != True:
    print (list_of_words[i],0,0)
```

Comment: And the language might be? (few people are interested in anything just tagged `string`. Also, syntax highlighting won't work unless you tag appropriately.) Looks pythonic to me.

Comment: It is python sorry I thought this was an all python website. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: search `WordSearch.py` file for a place where you replaced `str = ..` unless someone maliciously assigned to `builtins.str` somewhere.

Comment: I did do that I did not think it would interfere. Thank You.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Somewhere in your code (not in the part you have posted here) you have used the name `str` for a string. `str` is now that string, and not the built-in string type. You are attempting to call the string as though it were a function or type and Python is calling you out on it.

To avoid this problem, don't name your string `str`.

Comment: I did do that I did not think it would interfere but I guess it did. Thank you.

Comment: If you *must* call it something undescriptive like `str`, you can use `str_` or `_str`.

Comment: Personally I like calling such variables `text` rather than `str`.